# Real roots strictly between two adjacent integers for monic polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: polynomials

I am stuck trying to prove a problem that seems obvious: namely, given a monic polynomial with integral coefficients $$f(x)= x^n +a_1x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0, $$
$a_i\in \mathbb{Z}$, is it true that no pair of real roots lie strictly between any two adjacent integers?

I was able to prove it when $n=2$ and I have also sketched a proof for some $n$ that if such roots exist, then they will not be rational. Does this boil down to a nontrivial question or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: any two *adjacent* integers?

Comment: @Darij, exactly.

Comment: Why not choose two polynomials with roots between your favourite two consecutive integers, and then multiply them together? The product will have all the roots that the factors have.

Comment: @James, great. That solves it completely. I should really think before I post any questions. Please, close this question. Thank you.

Comment: @James: What about $n=3$?

Comment: The cubic $x^3-7x-7$ has two roots between $-2$ and $-1$.

Comment: @Chulumba, you have an opportunity to remove the question yourself.

Comment: Richard Stanley's solution generalizes for all $n\geq 3$; that is,  $x^{n-3}(x^3-7x-7)$.